# Calculadora con poo python

Tags: python, poo, herencia, class

Estoy intentando realizar una calculadora orientada a objetos con python, pero hasta este punto no se que hacer para que termine de funcionarme, esto es lo que llevo de codigo(Se deben ingresar 2 numeros y hacer cualquiera de las 4 operaciones)

```
class calculadora():
    num1= 0
    num2= 0


    def __init__(self,num1,num2):
        self.num1= float(num1)
        self.num2= float(num2)

    def sumar(self):
        suma = self.num1+self.num2
        print("el resultado de la suma es: ", suma)
    
    def restar(self):
        resta = self.num1-self.num2
        print("el resultado de la resta es: ", resta)

    def multiplicar(self):
        multiplicacion = self.num1*self.num2
        print("el resultado de la multiplicación es: ", multiplicacion)

    def dividir(self):
        divicion = self.num1/self.num2
        print("el resultado de la divición es: ", divicion)

num1 = input("ingrese un numero: ")
num2 = input("ingrese un numero: ")

calculadora = calculadora(num1,num2)
```

Comment: *"pero hasta este punto no se que hacer para que termine de funcionarme"* es un error bastante vago, no crees? Te propongo que especifiques qué es exactamente lo que no funciona para que así no tengamos que buscar nosotros también lo que falla. Por cierto, el fallo que veo a simple vista es, que creas el objeto pero **NUNCA** llamas a `calculadora.sumar()`

Comment: A parte de lo mencionado en invocar al método sumar a través del objeto calculadora, veo que le colocas parentesis a la clase, igual se me escapa algún detalle [pero así no es la sintaxis](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es eliminar los paréntesis en la declaración de la clase (innecesarios) y también las dos variables de clase `num1` y `num2`, ya que no se usan para nada.

```
class calculadora():
    num1= 0
    num2= 0
```

Aparte de eso, sólo queda llamar a los métodos deseados (sumar, restar, ...)

El código queda así:

```
class calculadora:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = float(num1)
        self.num2 = float(num2)

    def sumar(self):
        suma = self.num1 + self.num2
        print("el resultado de la suma es: ", suma)

    def restar(self):
        resta = self.num1 - self.num2
        print("el resultado de la resta es: ", resta)

    def multiplicar(self):
        multiplicacion = self.num1 * self.num2
        print("el resultado de la multiplicación es: ", multiplicacion)

    def dividir(self):
        divicion = self.num1 / self.num2
        print("el resultado de la divición es: ", divicion)


num1 = input("ingrese un numero: ")
num2 = input("ingrese un numero: ")

calculadora = calculadora(num1, num2)
calculadora.sumar()
calculadora.multiplicar()
calculadora.restar()
calculadora.dividir()
```

produce:

```
ingrese un numero: 10
ingrese un numero: 4
el resultado de la suma es:  14.0
el resultado de la multiplicación es:  40.0
el resultado de la resta es:  6.0
el resultado de la divición es:  2.5
```

Comment: Sería mejor si las funciones devolviesen algo con return, en este caso puede ser la cadena